# How to delete a “not applied” catalog price rule?

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog-price-rules

I tried to apply a Catalog Price rule but I received a "502 Bad Gateway" error message. When I returned in the Catalog Price Rules page/interface I deleted that rule but, after that, I had the "There are rules that have been changed but were not applied. Please, click Apply Rules in order to see immediate effect in the catalog." system message. It seems that rule is hanging in the queue so I can't apply any rules because the first rule in queue is that wrong.

How can I delete (from the database, I suppose) that wrong rule to apply?

Thans in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncate all tables that starts from `catalogrule_` and flush Magento cache (if you have no other rules).

If yoг want to just remove the message please run

```
delete FROM `core_flag` WHERE flag_code="catalog_rules_dirty";
```

I recommend to save the flag data somewhere to see the wrong rules IDs.

Comment: Won't this delete all the other rules? Seams kind of destructive and risky to me.

Comment: My fault, I supposed you have no other rules. Will update the answer in a few second

Comment: I tried but I continue to see that message "There are rules that have been changed but were not applied. Please, click Apply Rules in order to see immediate effect in the catalog."

And then, have I to truncate 'catalogrule' table too?

Comment: Have updated the answer

Comment: In 'flag_data' I have NULL value.
Should I delete this row or simply set "status" to 0?